# How to overload subscript operator with both read and write facility?

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

The following code is not compiling.

```
#include <bitset>
#include <iostream>

class Bits
{
public:
    std::bitset<4> bits;
public:
    Bits();
    Bits(Bits & b);
    Bits & operator = (Bits & b);
    bool   operator [] (int index) const; // For reading
    bool & operator [] (int index);       // For writing
};

Bits :: Bits() { }
Bits :: Bits(Bits & b)
{
    *this = b;
}

Bits &  Bits :: operator = (Bits & b)
{
    bits[0] = b.bits[0];
    bits[1] = b.bits[1];
    bits[2] = b.bits[2];
    bits[3] = b.bits[3];

    return *this;
}

bool Bits::operator [] (int index) const
{
   return bits[index];
}

bool & Bits::operator [] (int index)
{
   return bits[index];
}

int main()
{
    Bits bits;

    bits[0] = true;
    bits[1] = false;
    bits[2] = true;
    bits[3] = false;

    return 0;
}
```

Error:

```
1>------ Rebuild All started: Project: SubscriptOperatorOverloading, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>Deleting intermediate and output files for project 'SubscriptOperatorOverloading', configuration 'Debug|Win32'
1>Compiling...
1>Bits.cpp
1>e:\developer-workspace\subscriptoperatoroverloading\subscriptoperatoroverloading\bits.cpp(39) : error C2440: 'return' : cannot convert from 'std::bitset<_Bits>::reference' to 'bool &'
1>        with
1>        [
1>            _Bits=4
1>        ]
1>Build log was saved at "file://e:\Developer-Workspace\SubscriptOperatorOverloading\SubscriptOperatorOverloading\Debug\BuildLog.htm"
1>SubscriptOperatorOverloading - 1 error(s), 0 warning(s)
========== Rebuild All: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 skipped ==========
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Return `std::bitset<4>::reference` rather than `bool&`.

The reason `std::bitset<4>::reference` is not `bool&` is because (in a reasonable implementation) the elements of a `bitset` are *computed values* rather than objects; reading an element requires a computation and writing an element requires a computation, and thus the return value of `operator[]` cannot possibly be an ordinary reference.

Thus, `bitset<N>::reference` needs to be a *proxy* object; it is something that is convertible to `bool` (which does the correct calculation) and has an assignment operator (which does the correct calculation).